# Cordova iOS 3.6.3+ Issue - [__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Im getting following error in Xcode console:

```
-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174236680
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174236680
```

This causes the webView to stop responding to any touch events though the app remains working properly. For instance I can call a function from Safari web inspector console successfully.
Any ideas?

Comment: and do you know what causes it?

Comment: Well no idea, it happens at screen change, a couple of ajax calls fires and **navigator.notification.confirm()** will fired in one of the callbacks but no alert is popping up. But I can call even this from web inspector console successfully.

Comment: What part? It is too big to post it all here. And it worked fine with previous cordova version. I guess it is cordova problem, not my javascript. There are no errors in the web inspector. And android crashes completely at start up. BB10 works fine, just the alert is not popping up. Even when I call it from console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the problem. My fault.

There were wrong count of parameters for navigator.notification.confirm().

Small tip for cordova developers: Use JSON object as parameter for functions, then there will be no need for parameters such as null (because of the correct order and position of multiple parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in an app for the iPhone. I am porting an app from BlackBerry 10 to iOS. By the way we updated the cordova version.

The cordova API in cordova 4.0.0 has changed or is different on iOS.

In the BB10 app this code is working:

navigator.notification.alert("Test", function() {}, ["Info"]);

On iOS the array had to be removed:

navigator.notification.alert("Test", function() {}, "Info");